# Some confusion about Gaussian ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, gaussian-integers

Is $\mathbb{Z} [i] $ is field ? yes/No

yes, I thinks it will field  because it is integral domain

Is  its  True ?

Comment: Try to divide $1$ by $2$.

Comment: im not getting @darijgrinberg

Comment: $1/2 \notin \mathbb{Z}[i]$ but if it were a field, $2$ would have to have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is an integral domain.  Is it a field?  Why not?

Comment: Do you know the **definitions** of the words, "field", "integral domain"?  I ask because you say you think it is a field **because** it is an integral domain.  The set of all integers (with the usual addition and multiplication) is an integral domain  (that's where the name comes from) but not a field.  (Every field is an integral domain.  Not every integral domain is a field.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a field. For instance, $2$ has no inverse in $\mathbb Z[i]$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, ${\Bbb Z}[i] = \{a+bi\mid a,b\in{\Bbb Z}\}$ is a subset of ${\Bbb C}=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in{\Bbb R}\}$ and so an integral domain. But its clearly not a field.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. To see this, we know that $1$ is the identity in $\mathbb{Z}$, so how would we invert $2$? We would need to multiply it by $\frac{1}{2}$, which is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. In fact, the only invertible elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$, hence the integers do not form a field.

Hence, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not a field.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\mathbb Z[i]\cong\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1).$$

And $$(x^2+1)\subsetneq (3,x^2+1)\subsetneq\mathbb Z[x]\quad \text{(why?)}$$  implies $(x^2+1)$ is not a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[x]$, hence $\mathbb Z[i]$ is not a field.